# How to render Datatable using DT in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a R shiny app that reads many .xpt files and displays the data in a table. The user can also choose which file to display by selecting the 'selectInput' option.

I use DT here to render the dtatable so that filter boxes appear by default. Unfortunately, the DataTable is not rendered. I am not able to figure it out the issue.

One more help:
Since I am new to R shiny, I am not able to figure out where my datatable (on which variable, perhaps 'df') is kept so that I can use it to add extra functionality in the future.

**Data:**

**Mat.xpt:**

```
STUDYID DOMAIN  SUBID   MATSEQ
1        Mat    Mat_1    1
2        Mat    Mat_2    2
3        Mat    Mat_3    3
4        Mat    Mat_4    4
5        Mat    Mat_5    5
6        Mat    Mat_6    6
7        Mat    Mat_7    7
```

**Cap.xpt**

```
STUDYID DOMAIN  SUBID   MATSEQ
1        Cap    Cap_1    1
2        Cap    Cap_2    2
3        Cap    Cap_3    3
4        Cap    Cap_4    4
5        Cap    Cap_5    5
6        Cap    Cap_6    6
7        Cap    Cap_7    7
```

**code**

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      dataTableOutput("files_available")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$files_available <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    selectInput("name", str_to_title("select which file to show"), choices = input$file1$name)
  })
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    read_xpt(input$file1$datapath[[which(input$file1$name == input$name)]])
  })
  
  output$files_available <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(df(), filter="top",options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),callback=JS("
           //hide column filters for the first two columns
          $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
                $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()
              });"))})
  
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Use `renderDT` with `DTOutput`

Comment: @YBS, As I checked, it does not display the table

Comment: Please post some sample data in the question, so that I can verify.  I am not sure how your csv file looks like.

Comment: @YBS, Yes I have added the Xpt data in my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not specify the `csv` file, I am assuming that the `xpt` files are listed in the column `name`.  In that case the following should work.

[image: csv]

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  fdf <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$file1)){return(NULL)}
    inFile <- input$file1
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
  
  output$files_available <- renderUI({
    req(fdf())
    selectInput("name", str_to_title("select which file to show"), choices = fdf()$name)
  })

  df <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    read_xpt(input$name)
  })
  


  output$contents <- renderDT({
    datatable(df(), filter="top",options = list(lengthChange = FALSE) )
  })

### delete search in the first two columns

# output$contents <- renderDT({
#   datatable(df(), filter="top",options = list(lengthChange = FALSE),callback=JS("
#            //hide column filters for the first two columns
#           $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
#                 $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()
#               });"))
# })

 
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: When I uploaded the .xpt files, I can this error `Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
Warning in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on`

Comment: I did not get the results. I could see from the dropdown list "Select Which file to show" this shows me that you have uploaded a .xpt file, however it does not work for me when I upload the .xpt file and view the results. I anticipate that it will work with any. xpt file I hope. Looking for your help on this.

Comment: In my initial post, I updated with xpt files `Mat.xpt` and `Cap.xpt` to test.

Comment: Please note that my code works fine for me as I keep the xpt files in the same folder as the `app.R`.  I cannot help you anymore unless you show me how your csv file is organized. Please post a sample of the csv file.  What is in xpt files or their names is not an issue here.

Comment: Yes, I got it it works now. Thank you.

Comment: finally, How to bring the search boxes for all the columns? I can see the  first 2 of them are hidden.

Comment: You are hiding them in your callback.

Comment: Can you provide me any suggestions on how to fine-tune the callback function's parameters so that all of the search boxes are enabled?

Comment: You just delete the callback option. I have updated the code.

Comment: I checked the updated code and found that some of the search boxes are still blocked. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: I don't have that problem.  Please restart your RStudio session and try again.

Comment: To wrap up this discussion, I have one more question. I'm curious as to where the datable, or data frame, will be saved, and if it will be stored with 'df()'. Because I need to use'reactiveData(), observeEven()' to add a new column to the existing datatable to this app.

Comment: Yes, you can use `df()`.